# SQL Trigger signature capturing information on user creating/dropping an object

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I'm completely new to SQL, and am currently taking a class in it right now for databases. I am told to create a trigger signature that would capture information when anyone creates or drops an object.

I have no idea where to start, anything will help! I'm looking into trigger signatures right now but how do I know when someone creates/drops an object? So far I have been thinking it might be something like:

```
    BEFORE CREATE OR DROP
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In your* `sys` *or* `system` *schema, you can try trigger below;*

```
create or replace trigger trg_adm_ddl before ddl on database
declare
begin
 pr_ddl_oper;
end;

*where* pr_ddl_oper is ;

create or replace procedure pr_ddl_oper as
  v_oty          varchar2(75) := ora_dict_obj_type;
  v_don          varchar2(75) := ora_dict_obj_name;
  v_evt          varchar2(75) := ora_sysevent;
  v_olu          varchar2(75) := nvl(ora_login_user,'Unknown Schema');
  v_sql          ora_name_list_t;
  v_stm          clob;
  v_sct          owa.vc_arr;
  n              pls_integer;
  n_max          pls_integer := 10000;
begin
      v_sct(1) := 'SESSIONID';
      v_sct(2) := 'IP_ADDRESS';
      v_sct(3) := 'TERMINAL';
      v_sct(4) := 'OS_USER';
      v_sct(5) := 'AUTHENTICATION_TYPE';
      v_sct(6) := 'CLIENT_INFO';
      v_sct(7) := 'MODULE';
      for i in 1..7
      loop
       v_sct(i) := sys_context('USERENV',v_sct(i));
      end loop;
      select decode(v_sct(1),0,null,v_sct(1)),decode(upper(v_sct(3)),'UNKNOWN',null,v_sct(3)) into v_sct(1),v_sct(3) from dual;
       n := ora_sql_txt( v_sql );
      if n > n_max then
       n := n_max;
      end if;
      for i in 1..n
      loop
       v_stm := v_stm || v_sql(i);
      end loop;
       insert into usr_audit.log_ddl(col_datetime,col_user,col_evnt,col_statement,col_sessionid,col_ip,col_terminal,col_osuser,col_auttype,col_objecttype,col_objectname,col_clientinfo,col_moduleinfo)
       values(sysdate,v_olu,v_evt,v_stm,v_sct(1),v_sct(2),v_sct(3),v_sct(4),v_sct(5),v_oty,v_don,v_sct(6),v_sct(7));
end;
```

*after constructing this mechanism, you may enquiry the results with a sql like this one;*

> select * from usr_audit.log_ddl t 
>   where lower(t.stmt) like '%alter%table%modify%' 
>   order by t.col_datetime desc

**or you may use the below way easily (if your db is at least 11g);**

> $ alter system set enable_ddl_logging=true;

your `DDL log file` data is written in `XML` format to a file in your `OS`.